# Choosing Between Next.js 13 AppRouter and pure React for Admin Dashboard

Tags: reactjs, next.js, admin, dashboard, next.js13

Is it a good idea to use Next.js 13 App router for programming an admin dashboard, or should I build it as a single-page application using pure React?
Next.js seems to struggle with interactivity on slower connections. Which option offers better performance and interactivity?

I would like to know your opinion on the pros and cons of using Next.js 13 versus developing a clean React SPA for an admin dashboard. What are the potential benefits, drawbacks, and considerations in terms of interactivity? SEO is not important for this project.

Thank you for your insights

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest going for next.js 13

**Pros**

- New router makes it so easy to handle nested routes and if one request fails the dashboard won't crash
- You will get all the new fancy features like streaming ssr and more

You can see all the features in their demo [Here](https://vercel.com/templates/next.js/app-directory)

**Cons**

- Relatively new so there aren't many resources out there
- If you are using UI libraries like MUI they currently don't have support for server components [Read Here](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/styling/css-in-js)